# CruiseControl: Package Dependency Errors as Warnings in Build Log despite Successful Build!

Tags: config, cruisecontrol

My Errors and Warnings tab (CC dashboard) is rammed full of import failure errors, yet my build compiles?!

I notice that these failures have a log level of WARN.

Has anyone on here had this problem before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the errors were JavaDoc notifications... they just weren't stamped with [JavaDoc] !